# How to edit and save a Bundled Product "Bundle Items" link fields on Magento 2.4.6 PHP 8.1

Tags: magento2.4, bundled-product, save, product-links

I am writing a program that is checking product data and updating where required.

My problem is that I can't save a Bundled Products Bundle Items linked product fields such as price, price_type, qty, default etc. I can create a new linked item as part of an option, but I can't save the edited linked item.

My question is:

**How do I save a linked product field such as price within an option of the bundled items section for a bundled product?**

My code so far:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Process;

use Magento\Bundle\Api\ProductLinkManagementInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository;

class UpdateBundleProductLinks
{
    private ProductLinkManagementInterface $productLinkManagement;
    private ProductRepository $productRepository;

    public function __construct(
        ProductLinkManagementInterface $productLinkManagement,
        ProductRepository              $productRepository
    ) {
        $this->productLinkManagement = $productLinkManagement;
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    }


    public function execute(Product $product, array $productData): void
    {
        $productLinks = $this->productLinkManagement->getChildren($product->getSku());

        /* Iterate over each item in the $productData array */
        foreach ($productData['bundle_items'] as $bundleItem) {
            /* $productData['bundle_items'] has array of each linked products data, price, qty, price_type etc. */

            /* Iterate over links to find the match */
            foreach ($productLinks as $link) {

                if ($link->getSku() == $bundleItem['sku']) {
                    $update = false;

                    /* Check if links data matches */
                    if ($link->getPrice() != $bundleItem['price']) {
                        $link->setPrice($bundleItem['price']);
                        $update = true;
                    }

                    /* Check all links attributes here also ... */

                    if ($update) {
                        /* THIS IS WHERE I AM HAVING ISSUES SAVING THE LINK CHANGED DATA */

                        $this->productLinkManagement->saveChild($product->getSku(), $link);

                        /* I have tried saving the product after this point also without success */
                        $this->productRepository->save($product);
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Image below shows the admin product page section that I am trying to edit and save.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this code?

> Class file path :
> vendor/magento/module-catalog/Api/ProductLinkManagementInterface.php
> Function : public function setProductLinks($sku, array $items);
> This function accept sku and items array

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Process;

use Magento\Bundle\Api\ProductLinkManagementInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository;

class UpdateBundleProductLinks
{
    private ProductLinkManagementInterface $productLinkManagement;
    private ProductRepository $productRepository;

    public function __construct(
        ProductLinkManagementInterface $productLinkManagement,
        ProductRepository              $productRepository
    ) {
        $this->productLinkManagement = $productLinkManagement;
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    }


    public function execute(Product $product, array $productData): void
    {
        $productLinks = $this->productLinkManagement->getChildren($product->getSku());

        /* Iterate over each item in the $productData array */
        foreach ($productData['bundle_items'] as $bundleItem) {
            /* $productData['bundle_items'] has array of each linked products data, price, qty, price_type etc. */

            /* Iterate over links to find the match */
            foreach ($productLinks as $link) {

                if ($link->getSku() == $bundleItem['sku']) {

                    /* Check if links data matches */
                    if ($link->getPrice() != $bundleItem['price']) {
                        $link->setPrice($bundleItem['price']);

                        /*
                        Class file path : vendor/magento/module-catalog/Api/ProductLinkManagementInterface.php
                        Function : public function setProductLinks($sku, array $items);
                        this fucntion accept sku and items in array
                        */
                        $this->productLinkManagement->setProductLinks($product->getSku(), $link);
                    }

                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This tried to set Related / Cross-Sell / Up-Sell product option links, not bundle product links. I am trying to save the products that are within the Bundle Items / Option / Product.

Answer (score 0):

When updating the links as per the code I supplied, I was then using the $product variable further in my code and saving changes later on which was re-entering the old value. The solution I found is to reload the Product after `$this->productLinkManagement->saveChild($product->getSku(), $link)` and then return it.

Working Code:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Process;

use Magento\Bundle\Api\ProductLinkManagementInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository;

class UpdateBundleProductLinks
{
    private ProductLinkManagementInterface $productLinkManagement;
    private ProductRepository $productRepository;

    public function __construct(
        ProductLinkManagementInterface $productLinkManagement,
        ProductRepository $productRepository
    ) {
        $this->productLinkManagement = $productLinkManagement;
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    }


    public function execute(Product $product, array $productData): Product
    {
        $productLinks = $this->productLinkManagement->getChildren($product->getSku());
        $updated = false;

        /* Iterate over each item in the $productData array */
        foreach ($productData['bundle_items'] as $bundleItem) {

            foreach ($productLinks as $link) {

                if ($link->getSku() == $bundleItem['sku']) {
                    $update = false;

                    if ($link->getPrice() != $bundleItem['price']) {
                        $link->setPrice($bundleItem['price']);
                        $update = true;
                    }

                    /* Check all link attributes here ... */

                    if ($update) {
                        $this->productLinkManagement->saveChild($product->getSku(), $link);
                        $updated = true;
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if ($updated) {
            $product = $this->productRepository->get($product->getSku(), true, null, true);
        }
        return $product;
    }
}
```